# Javascript app laggy scroll in IOS7 devices

Tags: javascript, ios, chap-links-library

I've been using Chaps Link Timeline and it works well on all devices except on apple devices running iOS7. The problem is in the new iOS that is causing the lag. Basically scrolling (swiping left/right) on timeline is very laggy. Tested on both safari and chrome on an iPad. 
How can I fix lag in new iOS?

Timeline:
https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library/tree/master/js/src/timeline

Github Issue:
https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library/issues/239

Online Demo:
http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/examples/example01_basis.html

More Demos:
http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/timeline.html

Comment: iOS7 is claimed to be ~50% slower than it predecessors. So there's no easy way to fix it - especially if it has worked on iOS6 + other, then the performance of code shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Perhaps that claim only applies to old iphones which struggle running new OS... but I doubt that is the issue here. (http://www.phonearena.com/news/iOS-6-vs-iOS-7-did-performance-drop_id47575)

Comment: OK, we noticed in our case that where iOS6 performed UI operations in ~500ms, iOS7 required noticeably more time to perform same. This was an issue with hw-accelerated CSS transitions + DOM manipulation (not complex). But I'm unable to help with the Timeline you're using - just making sophisticated guess.